# Hello I am trying to use two models here: One which takes in account trend, The another one takes in account seasonality

Tags: python, statistics, tableau-api

I am new to the BI field and I was trying to predict the coronavirus cases for Italy. I am using tableau and exponential smoothing to predict cases. Both of my forecast(One with the trend, The other with seasonality) have Good model quality and Metrics. Which model should I choose?

[image: Multiplicative]

[image: Additive]

Comment: What makes you say they both have good metrics?

Comment: In the Summary, It said the Model is Good which is the highest-ranking tableau gives.